# do not store specific item in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I've tried different implementations using `remove_if`, `is_space`, and `find` but I still can't figure how to properly implement it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: I want to check if a character is a space symbol and if it is, do not store it in the character array.

```
for (int u = 0; u <= resultLength; u++) {
    resultLetters[u] = tolower(result[u]);
    if (result[u] == ' ') {
        // don't store me
    }
    cout << resultLetters[u] << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You want to know how to check if a character is a space symbol?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I want to check if a character is a space symbol and if it is, do not store it in the character array.

Comment: probably `<=` should be `<` in the loop condition, if `resultLength` is actually the number of characters in the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to "miss" spaces, like this:

```
int currentIndex = 0;
for (int u = 0; u <= resultLength; u++) {
    if (result[u] != ' ') {
        result[currentIndex] = tolower(result[u]);
        currentIndex++;
    }
    cout << result[u] << endl;
}
```

Note, that `currentIndex` will hold the length of the array after space removal.

Comment: One sticking point is the proper sizing of the `result` buffer. OP might need some advice in this sense :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a note that the resultLetters needed to be initialized with fill(resultLetters, resultLetters + 100, '0'); in order to have the correct values.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, then you might consider accepting it to help people having similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So, what `remove_if` / `isspace` code did you try? Used properly, they do work.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

resultLength = std::distance(
    std::begin(result),
    std::remove_if(std::begin(result),
                   std::advance(std::begin(result), resultLength),
                   [](char c) { return isspace(c); });

std::transform(std::begin(c), std::advance(std::begin(result), resultLength),
               [](char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
```

Comment: He has the length of the string as a variable, so `std::end` is not usable

Comment: @MattMcNabb: ah thanks - I'd read about the failed attempt with `remove_if` and not bothered looking at the current code, so the OP might have trouble applying my suggestions.  Edited.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int u = 0, int i = 0; u <= resultLength; u++) {
    if (result[u] != ' ') {
        resultLetters[i] = tolower(result[u]);
        i++;
    }
    cout << resultLetters[u] << endl;
}
```

resultLetters will have only the characcters other then ' ' (space char)